# Custom Metadata SOQL WHERE clause not working

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

I'm getting some weird behavior with a SOQL WHERE clause on a Custom Metadata Type query:

```sql
SELECT  Id, Label, DeveloperName, Version__c, Content__c 
FROM My_Text_Content__mdt WHERE Version__c = '2020'
```

The resulting dataset has about the right number of records, but it doesn't contain all the records where Version__c is "2020", and it contains some records whose Version__c is something other than "2020".

[image]

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: Is it picklist feild?

Comment: Good question -- no.  It's Text(20).

Comment: Is it sandbox, prod or scratch org?

Comment: It's a sandbox.

Comment: Can you try same query in prod? I think I somewhat saw similar in sandbox but it worked in prod.

Comment: I'm unable to deploy this custom metadata object to production yet for business reasons, but I did just run a query on another high-ish-volume custom metadata object in production with similar results.  In this case, I didn't have a text field to filter on, so I used a boolean/checkbox in the WHERE clause.  The results included many wrong records.

Answer (score 5):

Since there are more than 200 results, it could be a variation of [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008x3ZQAQ).

Try executing it as a script instead of a query:

```
List<My_Text_Content__mdt> myTextContents = [Select Id, Label, DeveloperName, Version__c, Content__c 
    FROM My_Text_Content__mdt WHERE Version__c = '2020' 
    ORDER BY Version__c];

for(My_Text_Content__mdt myTextContent: myTextContents){
    //Inspect results here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Same result, though, per System.debug. :-(  I actually saw that Known Issue in my original search, but ruled it out since the workaround looks the same as what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Upon further testing on other custom metadata types in our orgs, the issue seems to crop up when the expected result set is over 200 rows.  So although the script approach is not providing the hoped-for solution (and the official Salesforce workaround is useless from my perspective), I do agree these could be related issues.

Comment: The SFDC workaround doesn't pass the straight-face test - they should fix this.